# How to manage build, test and deployment with cypress and firebase

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment, cicd

I have a continuously growing website which has automated CI/CD using github actions. The website is build in React and using jest and cypress to do the testing. As for backend i'm using Firebase. Here is the workflow:

- Whenever a PR is created, github action will install the dependencies
  using yarn
- Create a test-build where Firebase emulators is used in order not to populate the prepod Firestore
- Create a preprod build with preprod API keys and a preprod Firestore and auth
- Test with jest up against the preprod build.
- If everything succeed it will publish the website to a temporary url.

All PR's are merged into the developer branch, but here is my question:
It seems very cumbersome and redundant to do the same steps whenever a PR is merged into the dev branch, but as of now, all of above steps are done again, but on the newly merged dev branch. Is that the normal way to do, or is it okay to skip this build, since it has already be done in the pr-merge or the PR?

Answer (score 0):

Your PR branches are tested in isolation, based on a previous dev branch (assuming that's where you forked from). Only if the PR branch was actively rebased against the dev branch, before merging, should you consider not re-running the full build on merges. Otherwise, you could run into a situation where multiple merges are happening, and the diff is clean for the individual PRs, but when put together within the dev branch, it no longer works.